# Return when a variable reach a certain value

Tags: c#

I have an inventory which contains five slots. When adding an item to my inventory, I check for the best slot. If all slots are full, I want to display a line in the console and return out of the method, but I'm having trouble figuring that part out. I know that the value of best slot would only go from 0 to 4, but my `if(bestSlot >= 4`) isn't working right.

```
int bestSlot = -1;
for (int i = 0; i < PlayerInventory.Items.Count(); i++)
{
  if (PlayerInventory.Items[i].ItemName == "empty")
  {
    if (bestSlot < 0)
    {
      bestSlot = i;
    }
  }
  else if (PlayerInventory.Items[i].ItemName != "empty")
  {
    if (PlayerInventory.Items[i].ItemName == item.ItemName)
    {
      bestSlot = i;
    }
  }
}

// add now
if (bestSlot >= 4)
{
  Console.WriteLine("inventory full");
  return;
}

if (bestSlot >= 0)
{ //add the item }
```

Right now, the item isn't being added to the inventory but the code in the `(bestSlot>= 0)` is still being ran and I have an empty slot in my inventory when the console displays the line.

Comment: Can you please provide more details to the state of your app. What items does PlayerInventory.Items contain. And what is the value of item - especially item.ItemName. Without that its hard to guess what your code will run like.

Comment: Also the last part is not clear: 1. Item isn't added because there is no code for it? because you said 2. bestSlot >= 0 is executed right?

Comment: You should bind emptyness of slot to PlayerInventory.Items[i] == null rather than .ItemName == "empty". You could accidentially have an item which's name is "empty".

Answer (score 0):

```
if (PlayerInventory.Items[4].ItemName != "empty" && PlayerInventory.Items[4].ItemName == item.ItemName)
{
  Console.WriteLine("inventory full");
  return;
}
```

On first read your question was not really clear, but I think you need this. You should delete for loop and everything in the loop bestSlot variable too. Right the needed code after this if.

Your problem is that you are going into all the elements of the PlayerIventory but you want to check only the 5. You can do this with the code which I show you.

Comment: @ChristianFrantz What are you expecting to be done, to consider working the logic working. You want if the 5 element is not empty and equal to item.ItemName to say inventory is full. If you don't want that explain what do you want ...